# Change html in text area dynamically in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: javascript, html, spotfire

I am trying to show html code dynamically in a text area in Tibco Spotfire. I have a table with 2 columns. One contains a keyword, the other one contains the respective html code.

Now, I would like to have this keyword column as a filter and the html part should dynamically align with the selections in the keyword filter.

Is that something I can realize with html + javascript in a text area?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery to accomplish this.

Please provide an example in your question for further help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with an IronPython script that you can attach to the table and run when something is marked. Once there is a marked selection in the table, the script can update text area contents. Let me know if you still need help with this.